# Test cases for Ansible lambda module for deployment of AWS Lambdas

Tags: python, unit-testing, amazon-web-services, ansible

I have written a set of test cases which cover the ansible lambda module.  The [entire source is available on GitHub](https://github.com/mikedlr/ansible/tree/aws_lambda_tests), forked from [ansible/ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible)

The [original file is visible on github](https://github.com/mikedlr/ansible/blob/aws_lambda_tests/test/units/modules/cloud/amazon/test_lambda.py) as is the [module, lambda.py it tests](https://github.com/mikedlr/ansible/blob/aws_lambda_tests/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/lambda.py)

I'd like to have a code review focusing on

- making the tests more reliable / less brittle
- making the code neater / better / more pythonic
- simply improving the value of the tests without adding many more

At the same time the test cases have to fit within the unit testing environment of Ansible so:

- they should work for early and modern python, at least 2.6,2.7 and 3.6
- the tests have to pass in the shippable environment used by ansible
- ansible uses it's own test runner based on pytest
- there are some special functions / modules that are expected to be used

  - ansible.compat.tests.mock / ansible.module_utils
- some hacks are needed to handle the way the module runs stand alone

In this version I don't want to change the way that lambda.py is written to improve its testability.  Before even considering that I'd like some basic tests in place so it can be refactored or replaced more safely.  Also the aim is simple / mostly static code which can be simply and easily debugged.

```
#
# (c) 2017 Michael De La Rue
#
# This file is part of Ansible
#
# Ansible is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# Ansible is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with Ansible.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

# Make coding more python3-ish

from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function)

from nose.plugins.skip import SkipTest
import pytest
import json
import copy
from ansible.module_utils._text import to_bytes
from ansible.module_utils import basic
from ansible.compat.tests.mock import MagicMock, Mock, patch
from ansible.module_utils.ec2 import HAS_BOTO3
if not HAS_BOTO3:
    raise SkipTest("test_ec2_asg.py requires the `boto3`, and `botocore` modules")

# lambda is a keyword so we have to hack this.
_temp = __import__("ansible.modules.cloud.amazon.lambda")

lda = getattr(_temp.modules.cloud.amazon,"lambda")

exit_return_dict={}

def set_module_args(args):
    args = json.dumps({'ANSIBLE_MODULE_ARGS': args})
    basic._ANSIBLE_ARGS = to_bytes(args)

base_start_function_config_in_aws={
    'FunctionName' : 'lambda_name',
    'Role' : 'arn:aws:iam::987654321012:role/lambda_basic_execution',
    'Handler' : 'lambda_python.my_handler',
    'Description' : 'this that the other',
    'Timeout' : 3,
    'MemorySize' : 128,
    'Runtime' : 'python2.7',
    'CodeSha256' : 'AqMZ+xptM7aC9VXu+5jyp1sqO+Nj4WFMNzQxtPMP2n8=',
}

one_change_start_function_config_in_aws=copy.copy(base_start_function_config_in_aws)
one_change_start_function_config_in_aws['Timeout']=4
two_change_start_function_config_in_aws=copy.copy(one_change_start_function_config_in_aws)
two_change_start_function_config_in_aws['Role']='arn:aws:iam::987654321012:role/lambda_advanced_execution'
code_change_start_function_config_in_aws=copy.copy(base_start_function_config_in_aws)
code_change_start_function_config_in_aws['CodeSha256']='P+Zy8U4T4RiiHWElhL10VBKj9jw4rSJ5bm/TiW+4Rts='

base_module_args={
    "region": "us-west-1",
    "name": "lambda_name",
    "state": "present",
    "zip_file": "test/units/modules/cloud/amazon/fixtures/thezip.zip",
    "runtime": 'python2.7',
    "role": 'arn:aws:iam::987654321012:role/lambda_basic_execution',
    "memory_size": 128,
    "timeout" : 3,
    "handler": 'lambda_python.my_handler'
}


#TODO: def test_handle_different_types_in_config_params(monkeypatch):


def test_update_lambda_if_code_changed(monkeypatch):

    fake_lambda_connection = MagicMock()
    fake_lambda_connection.get_function.configure_mock(
        return_value={
            'Configuration' : code_change_start_function_config_in_aws
        }
    )
    fake_lambda_connection.update_function_configuration.configure_mock(
        return_value={
            'Version' : 1
        }
    )
    fake_boto3_conn=Mock(return_value=fake_lambda_connection)

    set_module_args(base_module_args)
    @patch("ansible.modules.cloud.amazon.lambda.boto3_conn", fake_boto3_conn)
    def call_module():
        with pytest.raises(SystemExit):
            lda.main()

    call_module()

    # guard against calling other than for a lambda connection (e.g. IAM)
    assert(len(fake_boto3_conn.mock_calls) == 1), "multiple boto connections used unexpectedly"
    assert(len(fake_lambda_connection.update_function_configuration.mock_calls) == 0), \
        "unexpectedly updatede lambda configuration when only code changed"
    assert(len(fake_lambda_connection.update_function_configuration.mock_calls) < 2), \
        "lambda function update called multiple times when only one time should be needed"
    assert(len(fake_lambda_connection.update_function_code.mock_calls) > 1), \
        "failed to update lambda function when code changed"
    # 3 because after uploading we call into the return from mock to try to find what function version
    # was returned so the MagicMock actually sees two calls for one update.
    assert(len(fake_lambda_connection.update_function_code.mock_calls) < 3), \
        "lambda function code update called multiple times when only one time should be needed"

def test_update_lambda_if_config_changed(monkeypatch):

    fake_lambda_connection = MagicMock()
    fake_lambda_connection.get_function.configure_mock(
        return_value={
            'Configuration' : two_change_start_function_config_in_aws
        }
    )
    fake_lambda_connection.update_function_configuration.configure_mock(
        return_value={
            'Version' : 1
        }
    )
    fake_boto3_conn=Mock(return_value=fake_lambda_connection)

    set_module_args(base_module_args)
    @patch("ansible.modules.cloud.amazon.lambda.boto3_conn", fake_boto3_conn)
    def call_module():
        with pytest.raises(SystemExit):
            lda.main()

    call_module()

    # guard against calling other than for a lambda connection (e.g. IAM)
    assert(len(fake_boto3_conn.mock_calls) == 1), "multiple boto connections used unexpectedly"
    assert(len(fake_lambda_connection.update_function_configuration.mock_calls) > 0), \
        "failed to update lambda function when configuration changed"
    assert(len(fake_lambda_connection.update_function_configuration.mock_calls) < 2), \
        "lambda function update called multiple times when only one time should be needed"
    assert(len(fake_lambda_connection.update_function_code.mock_calls) == 0), \
        "updated lambda code when no change should have happened"

def test_update_lambda_if_only_one_config_item_changed(monkeypatch):

    fake_lambda_connection = MagicMock()
    fake_lambda_connection.get_function.configure_mock(
        return_value={
            'Configuration' : one_change_start_function_config_in_aws
        }
    )
    fake_lambda_connection.update_function_configuration.configure_mock(
        return_value={
            'Version' : 1
        }
    )
    fake_boto3_conn=Mock(return_value=fake_lambda_connection)

    @patch("ansible.modules.cloud.amazon.lambda.boto3_conn", fake_boto3_conn)
    def call_module():
        with pytest.raises(SystemExit):
            lda.main()

    call_module()

    # guard against calling other than for a lambda connection (e.g. IAM)
    assert(len(fake_boto3_conn.mock_calls) == 1), "multiple boto connections used unexpectedly"
    assert(len(fake_lambda_connection.update_function_configuration.mock_calls) > 0), \
        "failed to update lambda function when configuration changed"
    assert(len(fake_lambda_connection.update_function_configuration.mock_calls) < 2), \
        "lambda function update called multiple times when only one time should be needed"
    assert(len(fake_lambda_connection.update_function_code.mock_calls) == 0), \
        "updated lambda code when no change should have happened"

def test_dont_update_lambda_if_nothing_changed(monkeypatch):

    fake_lambda_connection = MagicMock()
    fake_lambda_connection.get_function.configure_mock(
        return_value={
            'Configuration' : base_start_function_config_in_aws
        }
    )
    fake_lambda_connection.update_function_configuration.configure_mock(
        return_value={
            'Version' : 1
        }
    )
    fake_boto3_conn=Mock(return_value=fake_lambda_connection)

    @patch("ansible.modules.cloud.amazon.lambda.boto3_conn", fake_boto3_conn)
    def call_module():
        with pytest.raises(SystemExit):
            lda.main()

    call_module()

    # guard against calling other than for a lambda connection (e.g. IAM)
    assert(len(fake_boto3_conn.mock_calls) == 1), "multiple boto connections used unexpectedly"
    assert(len(fake_lambda_connection.update_function_configuration.mock_calls) == 0), \
        "updated lambda function when no configuration changed"
    assert(len(fake_lambda_connection.update_function_code.mock_calls) == 0 ), \
        "updated lambda code when no change should have happened"

def test_warn_region_not_specified():

    set_module_args({
        "name": "lambda_name",
        "state": "present",
        # Module is called without a region causing error
        # "region": "us-east-1",
        "zip_file": "test/units/modules/cloud/amazon/fixtures/thezip.zip",
        "runtime": 'python2.7',
        "role": 'arn:aws:iam::987654321012:role/lambda_basic_execution',
        "handler": 'lambda_python.my_handler'})

    class AnsibleFailJson(Exception):
        pass

    def fail_json(*args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['failed'] = True
        raise AnsibleFailJson(kwargs)

    def call_module():
        with patch.object(basic.AnsibleModule, 'fail_json', fail_json):
            try:
                lda.main()
            except AnsibleFailJson as e:
                result = e.args[0]
                assert("region must be specified" in result['msg'])

    call_module()
```